# Nested application and absolute path of html tags

Tags: asp.net

The deal is that when you have the following on your site it works:

```
<a href="/Some/Path/file.aspx" class="button">Click Me!</a>
```

But the above fails to work if that site is a nested application.

I have seen two solutions to this opportunity in asp.net.

The first solution that I found was to add the following:

```
<a runat="server" href="~/Some/Path/file.aspx" class="button">Click Me!</a>
```

I have not tried this because I feel it would add more crap to your view state.

The solution that I have tried is:

```
<a href='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Some/Path/file.aspx") %>' class="button">Click Me!</a>
```

The question is, what is the preferred method of addressing paths in nested applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `HyperLink` server control. It is meant for that kind of thing.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink1" 
    NavigateUrl="~/Some/Path/file.aspx" 
    CssClass="button">Click Me!</asp:HyperLink>
```

Render as

```
<a id="HyperLink1" class="button" href="/Some/Path/file.aspx">Click Me1</a>
```

ASP.Net HyperLink control uses `ResolveClientUrl` to resolve the given url, so you do not need to do anything.

Comment: I have always worked under the impression that one should be stingy with the use of ASP.Net controls.  I did look at your recommendation as well as the two I listed and did not see any negative impact on the  pages view state.

Comment: You can get away with hyperlink and image controls. However, for maintenance and code cleanliness, you want to use server controls. Besides, you need to use a server control if you require to attach events. If you really want to control over html, you might want to consider looking into ASP.Net MVC.